# Best resources for best practices for scenarios of use?

Tags: scenarios

Over the next year, I'll be developing scenarios of use for a public health messaging system. I understand what scenarios of use are and why they are useful. What I would like is a how-to, best practices type guide to get me started in designing my workflow and scenarios of use study design. I'm particularly interested in scenarios of use development that uses semi-structured interview to inform the process.

Comment: You're asking a question here on a site of UX experts for our advice on where you can find useful UX information / resources? Why not just ask the question direct here to the UX experts? That's like going into a Mercedes dealer and asking if they know of a place where you can go and look at cars. Ask us the specific question about your particular scenario needs and we'll give you an answer about how best to put it into practice. Don't just ask for 'general best practices'; be specific to your requirement so you get a specific catered response.

Comment: I agree, the question is too wide ranging. A simple search for UX practises would steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, a simple search will steer me in the right direction. But it will not tell me what the best sources actually are. For that, I would need to consult with UX experts. That's people here. Search engines are good for one thing. Expert advice isn't it. That is why Stack Exchange exists. So does anyone have an answer? Thanks.

Comment: And also, a search for "best sources in UX" etc etc is not as good as answers here, because answers here are subject to reputational benefits and costs. Therefore the information I get is better. In case someone wanted to say, "Just search for best sources" etc etc

Comment: @Jon — In such a vast field, it is important to have a good guide when you are a beginner — as Brash seems to be. Nothing replaces a good human advice. When asking for general guidance, it is much better to ask to experts than to ask to Google. "Closing" this question is a bad idea.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: Just because this site is used by experts doesn't mean that *every* type of UX question is suitable. It's a Q&A site, not a UX discussion forum. It's designed for single questions to be asked and for specific answers to that question to be given.

Comment: @JonW: The question wasn't asking for a discussion. It was essentially asking for an annotated bibliography. People routinely ask such questions on Cross Validated, another Stack Exchange forum, and they routinely get answers. To this day, it confuses me why this question was closed and why it got the response it did.